# Imagick output image not updating in database

Tags: php, imagick

I retrieve image data from my database, use **Imagick** to manipulate it and then I write the output back to the database. The image is changed fine (in this case rotated) but it doesn't write back the changed image. Instead it writes back the original image.

```
$sql = "SELECT photoData FROM tblPhotos WHERE photoID = '..someID..';";
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $imagedata = $row['photoData'];
}

$im = new Imagick();
$im->readimageblob($imagedata);
$angle = 90;
$im->rotateimage("#FFF", $angle);
$output = $im->getimageblob();

$sql = "UPDATE tblPhotos SET photoData= '" . $output . "' WHERE photoID = '..someID..';";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

If I change the UPDATE $sql to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblPhotos SET photoData= 'abc' WHERE photoID = '..someID..';";
```

then I can see the UPDATE back to the database is working, so that is not the issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried "UPDATE tblPhotos SET photoData= '$output' WHERE photoID = '..someID..';"

Comment: Nice idea but it makes no difference. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Have you checked for any mysqli errors, using mysqli_error($connect) after the query?

Comment: There are none. As mentioned if i change data to photoData= 'abc' it saves correctly with no errors but of course the image is lost.